# Advantage of Spring Rest Web Services over Servlet

Tags: spring

What are the advantages of using Spring Rest Web Services over Core Servlet ?
 As we know Spring Rest Web Services also use Servlet internally.

Answer (score 1):

REST is a special kind of web service. Whether this is the right thing for your application varies. If it is you should use a framework/library that is designed for REST to make coding simpler. You might also want to have a look at JAX-RS.

If you need a non-REST web service Servlet may be an option, but there are other options, too.

Answer (score 0):

REST is not a type of Web Service - it is an Architecture and specification - JAX-RS. Spring has its own REST implementation libraries primarily based on its MVC controller. I would recommend you not to go for Spring Rest Web Services until you have any Spring specific requirement (Though I cant think of any such requirement which cant be solved by other light wait JAX-RS implementations). Jersey is the most light weight JAX-RS reference implementation by Sun/Oracle which, has support for Spring as well which, can be plugged in on requirement basis.